# Is there any other algorithms to find that a number is a prime number or not

Tags: algorithm

I always use that code to control if a number is prime or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long i, n;
    int s;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%llu", &n);

    if (n != 2) {
        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n%i == 0) {
                s = 0;
                break;
            }
            else {
                s = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        s = 1;
    }

    if (s == 1) {
        printf("Prime.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Not prime.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when i enter a very big number such as 1365165888711511, it takes very long time. (I'm waiting it for an hour. (CPU:2.90GHz*4,RAM:8GB))

My question; is there any other way to check numbers faster than the algorithm above?

Comment: This is really a mathematics / algorithmic question opposed to code - Fermat's little theorem is the first place to check, and will lead you to Carmichael numbers and a lovely branch of mathematics. You could ask it on the mathematics overflow site, but such a basic topic should be researched first - there is plenty of material.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: This isn't programming, this is "find a better way of doing it", which won't be programming until you decide what that better way is.

Comment: i m going to look at the primality tests, but i want to know; how isprime() function works?

Comment: Depends on which `isprime()` you are talking about..

Comment: The C header `<ctype.h>` doesn't define `isprime`, perhaps you mean some other kind of `ctype`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should cut down the execution time to a matter of minutes rather than hours, at least for numbers that are prime:

```
 for (i=3; i*i <= n; i += 2){
    if (n % i == 0) {
        s=0;
        break;
    }
```

This is `O(sqrt n)` no matter the primality of `n`. Your code was `O(n)` for prime `n`. It's also about twice as fast in general, due to the `i += 2` line.

To make it even faster than that, you'll need a probabilistic test, such as [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).:

```
Input: n > 3, an odd integer to be tested for primality;
Input: k, a parameter that determines the accuracy of the test
Output: composite if n is composite, otherwise probably prime
write n − 1 as 2^s·d with d odd by factoring powers of 2 from n − 1
WitnessLoop: repeat k times:
   pick a random integer a in the range [2, n − 2]
   x ← a*d mod n
   if x = 1 or x = n − 1 then do next WitnessLoop
   repeat s − 1 times:
      x ← x^2 mod n
      if x = 1 then return composite
      if x = n − 1 then do next WitnessLoop
   return composite
return probably prim
```

Note that this can be deterministic for a lot of values:

> When the number n to be tested is small, trying all a < 2(ln n)^2 is not necessary, as much smaller sets of potential witnesses are known to suffice. For example, Pomerance, Selfridge and Wagstaff[8] and Jaeschke[9] have verified that

```
if n < 2,047, it is enough to test a = 2;
if n < 1,373,653, it is enough to test a = 2 and 3;
if n < 9,080,191, it is enough to test a = 31 and 73;
if n < 25,326,001, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, and 5;
if n < 4,759,123,141, it is enough to test a = 2, 7, and 61;
if n < 1,122,004,669,633, it is enough to test a = 2, 13, 23, and 1662803;
if n < 2,152,302,898,747, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, and 11;
if n < 3,474,749,660,383, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13;
if n < 341,550,071,728,321, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, and 17.
```

> Using the work of Feitsma and Galway enumerating all base 2 pseudoprimes in 2010, this was extended (see OEIS A014233), with the first result later shown using different methods in Jiang and Deng:[10]

```
if n < 3,825,123,056,546,413,051, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, and 23.
if n < 2^64, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, and 37.
```

> Sorenson and Webster[11] verify the above and calculate precise results for these larger than 64-bit results:

```
if n < 318,665,857,834,031,151,167,461, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, and 37.
if n < 3,317,044,064,679,887,385,961,981, it is enough to test a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, and 41.
```

Comment: It may be faster to compute `sqrt(n)` once rather than `i*i` for every iteration. And do you have a typo? `if n < 264,`

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, that should have been `2^64`, copy paste error. Precomputing `sqrt(n)` might be a little faster, but IIRC it didn't make a difference when I tried it once in C.

Answer (score 0):

One very quick way to speed up your algorithm is to only go up to the square root of n and increment by 2 to avoid trying to divide by even numbers which will always fail if 2 fails. But some googling will find you some more complex algorithms, as this is a very crucial part of cryptography. Some things to help you on your search are:
"Fortunately in practice there are more complex algorithms for finding prime numbers. Such are the sieves of Euler, Atkin and Sundaram."
Taken from this site: [how to find primes](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/05/08/computer-algorithms-determine-if-a-number-is-prime/)
Note that this is not my link.